# Collect lines offset in bytes via TextFieldParser class

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv

To quickly navigate to some lines in CSV file I need to remember their positions in a given file in bytes. I am using `TextFieldParser` class. Using `TextFieldParser` I want to process data in a file and I also want to remember the offset in bytes of some lines. Is this possible?

I'm confused with the data returned by Position method because while `TextFieldParser.ReadLine` method advances through the file, `Position` method returns the same value (5120) until line number 62.

```
Dim FStream As FileStream = File.Open("p.csv", FileMode.Open)
' My plan is to pass to this methond some offset in bytes from
' beginning of file so when csvReader.ReadLine() is called it reads
' needed line.
'FStream.Seek(5120, SeekOrigin.Begin)
Using csvReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(FStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
    csvReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    csvReader.SetDelimiters(";")
    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False
    csvReader.TrimWhiteSpace = True

    While csvReader.LineNumber < 100
        Try
            Dim aa = csvReader.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine(aa)
            Console.WriteLine("Line number {0}. Position: {1}", csvReader.LineNumber, FStream.Position())
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End While

    outputFile.Close()
End Using
```

Here is output:

```
1
storage_code;article;brand;description;delivery_time;count_text;miltiplity_;price
Line number 2. Position: 5120
Bella333;SLHGO038;NAMDO;"ODL mdiriuo fofofof";0/2;2;1;.59,10
... It prints «Position: 512» until line 62 when it outputs «Position: 9216»...
```

Comment: I've not researched it specifically but, judging by what you are saying, the `TextFieldParser` must read a chunk of data into a buffer and then read text from that.  That makes sense because reading byte by byte from a buffer to find a field or record delimiter would be far more efficient than doing it from the file system.

Comment: My guess would be that a `TextFieldParser` uses a `StreamReader` internally - it can take one as a constructor argument and probably creates one otherwise.  The `StreamReader` class buffers data for the very reason I mentioned.  It can't know where a line ends without having read to the end of a line so it will read past the end of a line and then return text only up to the line break.  I think that, in order to do what you want, you'd have to actually count `Bytes` yourself by converting the text you read back to a `Byte` array.

Comment: The stream specified in the contructor is used as a source only. It's position, after it's been "used", will be set at the end of the file.You could update the position of the source stream (if needed, an Integer variable would do) while reading the text lines. After the `TextFieldParser` initialization: `FStream.Position = [InitialPosition]`  then `FStream.Position += aa.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length`